# how to use records as parameters in stored function

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

I want to use record type as parameter but I got message that function cannot have record type parameters. I have a `Dao` function which perform various operation on a `Arraylist` passed through parameter and I need to implement it in stored procedure. So any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks!
The function m looking for is something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION est_fn_get_emp_report(rec record,...)
```

I am new using **postgresql** but have used stored functions before but never have to use record type parameters.

Comment: hello, you cannot do it in PL/pgSQL. PLpgSQL can have composite type parameters, but parameter should not be polymorphic - it should be of declared type or table type.

Comment: thanks sir, does it mean that if i create a 'type' in my database and use it as parameter to function will it work?

Comment: yes, plpgsql can work with composite types

Comment: ok that was very much useful for me sir, thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

The simple issue is you can't specify a record.  You can specify some polymorphic types (ANYARRAY, ANYELEMENT) as an input of a function but it needs to have a structure known at planning time and this can lead to issues with polymorphic types as input args on even on a good day.  The problem with a record is that PostgreSQL wont necessarily know what the internal structure is when it is passed in.  `ROW(1, 'test')` is not useful in a functional context.

Instead you want to specify complex types.  You can actually take this very far in terms of relying on PostgreSQL.  This allows you to specify a specific type of record when passing it in.